# Unable to get reviews from Yelp API using tmhOAuth php library. I get NO ERRORS

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, yelp

I am using Matt Harris's tmhOAuth library to generate an authenticated request to Yelp's API. I am already using the same library to access the Twitter API and it works well.

I have signed up for Yelp Developer API credentials and am using them.

I set up tmhOAuth to make a request like:

http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?limit=20&location=Atlanta&term=food

My hunch is somehow my authentication credentials are not being output correctly, even though you would think I would get some sort of error from Yelp about this. For example, I change my consumer key and secret and my user token and secret to random characters, but when I make a request with these bogus keys I get the same response as below and STILL no authentication error message. Just NOTHING!

I feel certain that someone else, when they were first setting up their calls to the Yelp API may have run into a similar response and tell me something obvious that I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The response I get from Yelp is:

```
Array ( 
   [headers] => Array ( 
     [date] => Sat, 03 Nov 2012 21:36:15 GMT 
     [server] => Apache
     [x_node] => wsgi, web31,  api_com 
     [content_length] => 0 
     [cache_control] => max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store, private 
     [expires] =>  Sat, 03 Nov 2012 21:36:15 GMT
     [pragma] => no-cache [set_cookie] => bse=0aff211810c8d90f05c4e8438a3e0b7b; Domain=.yelp.com; Path=/; HttpOnly 
     [location] => http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?limit=20&location=Atlanta&term=food  
     [vary] => User-Agent 
     [connection] => close 
     [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8 
     [x_mode] => rw 
     [x_proxied] =>  lb2 
   ) 
   [code] => 301 
   [response] => 
   [info] => Array ( 
     [url] => https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?limit=20&location=Atlanta&term=food 
     [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8 
     [http_code] => 301 
     [header_size] => 534 
     [request_size] => 439 
     [filetime] => -1 
     [ssl_verify_result] => 0 
     [redirect_count] => 0 
     [total_time] => 0.653941 
     [namelookup_time] => 0.000981 
     [connect_time] => 0.073796 
     [pretransfer_time] => 0.297663 
     [size_upload] => 0 
     [size_download] => 0 
     [speed_download] => 0 
     [speed_upload] => 0  
     [download_content_length] => 0 
     [upload_content_length] => 0 
     [starttransfer_time] => 0.653791 
     [redirect_time] => 0 
     [certinfo] => Array ( ) 
     [request_header] => GET 

       /v2/search?limit=20&location=Atlanta&term=food 
       HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: themattharris' HTTP 
       Client Host: api.yelp.com Accept: */* Authorization: OAuth 
       oauth_consumer_key="****************", 
       oauth_nonce="*******************", 
       oauth_signature="***************************", 
       oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
       oauth_timestamp="1351978544", 
       oauth_token="******************", 
       oauth_version="1.0" 
     ) 
   )
```

I've obviously obfuscated the actual key, nonce and signature strings above for this post.

Comment: Please copy/paste the `var_dump()/print_r()` output from _the page source_ rather than as displayed and rendered by the browser. It will have line breaks and indentation intact, to make it readable.

Comment: Sorry. Geez, I knew I'd post a question and the very first response would be a slap on the hand. Of course, you are right, it is more legible, no question. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Great. The first actual bona-fide question I post here after years of using StackOverflow by simply reading the answers to other people's questions, and I have to eat humble pie and answer the question myself:

First off, most of the response array I listed above is constructed by the oAuth library itself. The actual "response" from Yelp was stored in the [response] array item and it was empty.

I asked myself, "When does a website give no response?" if by response we mean, no page content, it is only when it sends down some instructions to the browser in the http header.

Of course, Yelp HAD responded. It wanted to redirect me from a https:// url to a http:// url, so it responded with the response code 301, which tells a *browser* to retry at a different url, but I was using cUrl and curl did not redirect automatically. It simply passed on the initial server response to the oAuth lib, which was dutifully reporting the 301.

I had tried an http:// url earlier, but the way to do that was pass a param to the oAuth lib  as the array item 'use_https' => false. I had erroneously put 'false' as a string, so it evaluated to TRUE and continued to use https:// and the 301 redirect was still sent down.

The second I started using 'use_https' => false, I got my beloved Yelp reviews filling the screen like manna from heaven.

But perhaps my ridiculous travails will help some other poor soul, I hope.